# How to use isnull and round

Tags: sql, null

In SQL, I use only round, but it comes up with null data. I need to see if it’s null, 0.

```
SELECT  
  ( ROUND((1 - ((5-t1.MeanScore) * .15)) * 06,1)) as overall,
    + ISNULL(t1.[Final Grade] , 0)
    +  ROUND((1 - ((4-t1.MeanScore) * .15)) * 06,1) 
ENS AS Total
  from grades t1
```

This 'MeanScore' value is null. So the total comes out as null. Also, I want the overall value to be 0.

I need the total value to be not null, and the overall value is 0. Not null.

Comment: Please can edit your question and share some simple and the expected output ?

Comment: Also tag the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

ISNULL
Return the specified value IF the expression is NULL, otherwise return the expression:
Ex: SELECT ISNULL(NULL, 'test');
Result : test

ROUND
The ROUND() function rounds a number to a specified number of decimal places.

SELECT ROUND(235.415, 2) AS RoundValue;
Result : - 235.420

Comment: Yes, some data is null so it come up null. what i couldnt make it is in my code there is some calculation. i dont know where to put 'isnull' and where to put 'round' functions

Comment: if you get result not null then you used isnull and if you get floating point value then you use round

isnull function check value is null or not null 
round function is check floating point number

Comment: @user22168985 i think you need 

SELECT ROUND(ISNULL(235.415,0), 2)

Comment: Like HTML, (single) line breaks do not render here. You may want to [change](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76653228/edit) it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the standard SQL function `COALESCE`. Just replace each `t1.MeanScore` appearance with `COALESCE(t1.MeanScore, 0)`:

```
SELECT  
    ROUND(1 - (5 - COALESCE(t1.MeanScore, 0) * .15)) * 06, 1) as overall,
    -- rest of query
FROM grades t1
```